# Connecting HTML iFrame to database

Tags: database, dynamic, velo

I have a database connected to dynamic pages. One of the columns in the database is an HTML embed code that I would like embedded on each page.

Is there a way of hardcoding the content of the database to an HTML Embed Frame via Velo? If so, how can this be done exactly?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way (click and play) but you can pass the html using `postMessage` from the website to the iframe.

For example:

Website code:

```js
$w('#html1').postMessage(htmlFromTheDatabase)
```

HTML component code

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('message', message => {
        console.log('message', message.data);
        document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML = message.data
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://moshef9.wixsite.com/html-from-db